# PostgreSQL, Query non existed table

Tags: postgresql

I have table which may and may not exist and I query it like this:

```
SELECT value FROM mysetups WHERE mysetting='my_setup';
```

In case table 'mysetups' exists that work OK but if not then I get an error.
I have idea to get NULL or empty string in such case. Like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(value, NULL) FROM mysetups WHERE mysetting='my_setup';
```

But that also generate an error (42P01, ERROR: relation "mysetups" does not exist).
Can this be done that PostgreSQL service such error inside of it and simply return NULL or empty string if table don't exist?

I know how to check if table exists but I thought that maybe here is a way to do that in single SELECT query?

Comment: I think you would need to wrap your query inside function, don't see any option in plain query.

Comment: The optimizer can't do anything if you reference a missing object.  It's like referencing a variable in C when you haven't declared it, the compiler is going to throw an error.

Comment: OK, my idea was to check if IF EXISTS may be extended (and used) with SELECT statement like we can use that in CREATE TABLE or similar cases. Thanks.